# SQL server to XML using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, xml, eclipse

I am trying to take data out of a table in SQL Server, using Java(eclipse) and trying to create and write the data into XML file. I am getting "Source not found" I have gone through some other posts and tutorials and have added the project files in but am still getting the same error. This is the code

```
package q3;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.*;


public class Asign33 {
public static Connection connection;

static String sUsername = "s_aha";
static String sPassword= "aaaa";
 static String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://cypress;" +
            "user = " + sUsername + ";" +
            "password = " + sPassword;

public Asign33(){

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element element = document.createElement("GPASummary" );
document.appendChild(element);



    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        try {
            Connection mycon = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.println("connected");    
            Statement stmt=mycon.createStatement();
            String Query ="SELECT StudentNo, FirstName, LastName, GPA FROM Students";
            ResultSet stud= stmt.executeQuery(Query);

            String Fname,Lname;
            String sno;
            String gpa;
            while(stud.next()){
                System.out.println("in while"); 

                /*Attr attr = document.createAttribute("Student");
                attr.setValue("1");
                element.setAttributeNode(attr);
                */
                sno=stud.getString(1);
                Fname=stud.getString(2);
                Lname=stud.getString(3);
                gpa=stud.getString(4);

                Element StudentNo= document.createElement("StudentNo");
                StudentNo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sno));
                element.appendChild(StudentNo);

                Element FirstName= document.createElement("FirstName");
                FirstName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Fname));
                element.appendChild(FirstName);

                Element LastName= document.createElement("LastName");
                LastName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Lname));
                element.appendChild(LastName);

                Element GPA= document.createElement("GPA");
                GPA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(gpa));
                element.appendChild(GPA);


            }
            System.out.println("out of while"); 

TransformerFactory transformerFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
System.out.println("tranformer ");  

StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\aha\\Documents\\gpaSummary.xml"));

transformer.transform(source, streamResult);

System.out.println("Stream written");   

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
    return;
    }
    }
    }
```

I believe I am getting the error at
transformer.transform(source, streamResult);

Sorry for the mess of a code, first time using java. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What exact exception are you getting?

Comment: Source not found. that is the only message that I see when I debug.